# Android native code not creating AudioRecord on Asus Tinkerboard 2S

Tags: android, audiorecord, audioflinger

I am trying to use Picovoice on the Tinkerboard 2S and I am getting these logs when trying to initialise a process

```
2023-10-20 20:58:02.838   282-520   AudioFlinger            audioserver                          E  createRecord() getInputForAttr return error -38
2023-10-20 20:58:02.838  5915-5994  IAudioFlinger           com.hussell.dukebox                  E  createRecord returned error -38
2023-10-20 20:58:02.838  5915-5994  AudioRecord             com.hussell.dukebox                  E  createRecord_l(336073480): AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -38
2023-10-20 20:58:02.838  5915-5994  AudioRecord-JNI         com.hussell.dukebox                  E  Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -38.
2023-10-20 20:58:02.839  5915-5994  android.me...udioRecord com.hussell.dukebox                  E  Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2023-10-20 20:58:02.840  5915-5915  PorcupineManager        com.hussell.dukebox                  E  ai.picovoice.android.voiceprocessor.VoiceProcessorStateException: Audio recorder did not initialize successfully. Ensure you have acquired
                                                                                                    permission to record audio from the user.
```

Firstly, I have the right permissions in the Manifest and I have validated that the permissions are enabled for audio recording through the device as well, as well as requesting the permission at runtime when the app is first installed.

I have gone through the Java source code and can't see why it'd be wrong there, and it does seem to be in the native libraries. I really don't know what could be causing this. I have tried to initialise the process at different times, well after everything else in the system is initialised, but no luck. I have tried a few different versions of Android for this board, but still not luck there.

I have also asked this question in the TinkerBoard forums, but I am asking here since maybe it is more generic to the OS.

Update: I have noticed that I do not have pcmC0D0p in the audio devices directory.

```
crw-rw---- 1 system audio 116,   6 2013-01-18 08:50 controlC1
crw-rw---- 1 system audio 116,   8 2013-01-18 08:50 controlC2
crw-rw---- 1 system audio 116,   5 2013-01-18 08:50 pcmC1D0p
crw-rw---- 1 system audio 116,   7 2013-01-18 08:50 pcmC2D0p
crw-rw---- 1 system audio 116,  33 2013-01-18 08:50 timer
```

Is it safe to just change the naming of these to see if it fixes it?

Comment: -38 is INVALID_OPERATION, for what it's worth. But you will have to debug the audio interface source code to find out why..

Comment: I found in the Linux system underneath Android that the audio drivers were changing. With the Mic unplugged, all gets set up correctly. Here is the link to the stack exchange thread. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253699/android-linux-system-is-changing-the-audio-drivers-on-boot-with-usb-mic-attached
I am not sure how I would debug the audio interfac itself, to be honest.